# How to shut off water from city meter with no customer shut-off valve

Tags: plumbing, leak, plumbing-fixture, water-damage, shutoff

I want to shut off the water from the main city supply in order to repair my main water valve inside the house.  But there doesn't seem to be any shut-off valve, Please refer to pictures [image]

Comment: There is no shutoff out near the curb?

Comment: Don't know where you are located, but I'm pretty sure you're not technically supposed to touch the city's water meter. My neighbor did this exact thing and ended up breaking off the head of their valve and it cost him an arm and a leg for them to replace it. But it looks like you could flip up that blue cover and there will most likely be a shutoff valve under it. But again.....do so at your own risk.

Comment: @roasthead the meter dials are under the cap.

Comment: Makes sense......I've never seen a meter that looks like this one, just the meter in my front yard.

Comment: You say "repair". Do you have an active leak there? If so, call the city and tell them that you've got a leak at your main shut off and they need to come shut off your water so you can do the repair. It's _possible_, since the main shut-off is _inside_ your house, that the city will take responsibility for repairing that shut off since there's no other way for you to do it. Also, making them aware of this will likely result in a credit on your bill for the water that leaked through no fault of your own. At least you'll have something to argue from by notifying them.

Comment: Try digging straight down ; valve boxes have a tendency to fill with soil. It is hard to believe a city would put in a meter that they could not easily shut off to replace.

Comment: Some have suggested to lift the cap. The only thing there is the meter itself. No valves

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have a shutoff below the dirt level or at the house you can pack dry ice around a short section of pipe and that will freeze the water and make a plug .

I have done this with galvanized and copper never tried plastic . Only an inch or 2 being frozen will plug the pipe and not break it. I have had to do this when I had to replace the main shutoff valve.

Comment: WOW, clever. Never would have thought of that!  Learn something every day here!+

Comment: I use dry ice and have for over 40 years I have co2 and a dry ice expansion block so I can make it any time, safer than propane cheaper than a can of “air” or “freeze spray” or R134 most people call Freon yes caned air or freeze spray is r134 read the label , if used in a refrigerator or ac you have to be licensed.   with dry ice it works when the main shutoff valve has failed. I have used it where I only needed 1 branch and not an entire building.

Answer (score 1):

The blue cap is just the cover over the meter glass where the useage reading is.  It looks like you have a meter riser installed.  It is used when the city needs to raise the height of the meter.  If you dig around on the City side you should find the city shut off.  There is one there for sure.  You will find a brass bar about 1.25 inch long and about 1/2 inch wide.   If you want to shut it off, get a large cresent wrench and adjust it to fit the brass bar.  Stand the wrench up and put a large screw driver through the hole in the wrench handle and carefully turn clockwise.  Should turn about 180 degrees.  Don't force it too much as it is brass and you can snap it off.  And yes you are not supposed to be turning it, If you break it, you pay for the repairs.  27 yr's working for city water dept

Comment: Great input, charlie, thanks for contributing and welcome to [diy.se]. Listing your background there does lend more than a bit of credibility to your answer, too. ;) Take a moment between questions to take the [tour] and read through the [help] so you can learn how to make the most of the site.